# How to debug slow cassandra query traces

Tags: cassandra

We are seeing frequent slow queries from our Cassandra (version 2.1.12 ) cluster the one below is an example from a trace that took almost 150ms (or 50th percentile is around 5ms). The data over which all of these queries is run is mostly non-changing and request volume is relatively low. The keyspace for the query is as follows: The following are two traces of the slow query logs:

```
CREATE TABLE "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (
    field1 text,
    field2 text,
    field3 boolean,
    last_modified bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (field1, field2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (field2 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Seemingly random operations `Seeking to partition beginning in data file`
 and `Enqueuing response to /0.0.0.1` seem to take over 100ms. Anyone seen these kind of traces before? What can I do to investigate more?

```
Trace:
Host (queried):XXXX.XXXX.com/0.0.0.1:9042
Host (tried): XXXX.XXXX.com/0.0.0.1:9042
Trace id: ab846ae0-6b95-11e6-ad5d-7d0826b4ac3d
timestamp                | source   |source_elapsed| Description
-------------------------+----------+--------------+--------------
2016-08-26T14:02:05.326Z | /0.0.0.1 |           33 |                                        reading data from /0.0.0.2
2016-08-26T14:02:05.327Z | /0.0.0.1 |           73 |                                  Sending READ message to /0.0.0.2
2016-08-26T14:02:05.331Z | /0.0.0.2 |            9 |                               READ message received from /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:02:05.422Z | /0.0.0.2 |          233 |            Executing single-partition query on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2016-08-26T14:02:05.427Z | /0.0.0.2 |          239 |                                           Acquiring sstable references
2016-08-26T14:02:05.429Z | /0.0.0.2 |          248 |                                            Merging memtable tombstones
2016-08-26T14:02:05.430Z | /0.0.0.2 |          260 |                                          Key cache hit for sstable 459
2016-08-26T14:02:05.431Z | /0.0.0.2 |          261 |                            Seeking to partition beginning in data file
2016-08-26T14:02:05.445Z | /0.0.0.2 |       102921 | Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones
2016-08-26T14:02:05.446Z | /0.0.0.2 |       102923 |                             Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables
2016-08-26T14:02:05.447Z | /0.0.0.2 |       107862 |                                    Read 501 live and 0 tombstone cells
2016-08-26T14:02:05.447Z | /0.0.0.2 |       107902 |                                    Enqueuing response to /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:02:05.466Z | /0.0.0.2 |       134315 |                      Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:02:05.473Z | /0.0.0.1 |       147284 |                   REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /0.0.0.2
2016-08-26T14:02:05.474Z | /0.0.0.1 |       147302 |                                 Processing response from /0.0.0.2




Trace:
Host (queried):xxxxxx.xxxx.com/0.0.0.1:9042
Host (tried): xxxxxxx.xxxx.com/0.0.0.1:9042
Trace id: 9930d290-6b9d-11e6-ae36-ddb3c9ba6cb9
timestamp                | source   |source_elapsed| Description
-------------------------+----------+--------------+--------------
2016-08-26T14:58:50.553Z | /0.0.0.2 |            8 |                                READ message received from /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.556Z | /0.0.0.1 |           39 |                                         reading data from /0.0.0.2
2016-08-26T14:58:50.557Z | /0.0.0.1 |           89 |                                   Sending READ message to /0.0.0.2
2016-08-26T14:58:50.563Z | /0.0.0.1 |        10186 |                    speculating read retry on XXXXXX.XXXXX.com/0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.565Z | /0.0.0.1 |        10246 |                      Sending READ message to XXXXXX.XXXX.com/0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.570Z | /0.0.0.1 |        10322 |                                READ message received from /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.593Z | /0.0.0.2 |        39803 |            Executing single-partition query on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2016-08-26T14:58:50.600Z | /0.0.0.2 |        39894 |                                           Acquiring sstable references
2016-08-26T14:58:50.600Z | /0.0.0.2 |        39898 |                                            Merging memtable tombstones
2016-08-26T14:58:50.601Z | /0.0.0.2 |        39908 |                                          Key cache hit for sstable 495
2016-08-26T14:58:50.601Z | /0.0.0.2 |        39909 |                            Seeking to partition beginning in data file
2016-08-26T14:58:50.602Z | /0.0.0.2 |        42002 | Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones
2016-08-26T14:58:50.603Z | /0.0.0.2 |        42004 |                             Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables
2016-08-26T14:58:50.604Z | /0.0.0.2 |        49181 |                                    Read 501 live and 0 tombstone cells
2016-08-26T14:58:50.604Z | /0.0.0.2 |        49207 |                                     Enqueuing response to /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.646Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92529 |            Executing single-partition query on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2016-08-26T14:58:50.648Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92642 |                                           Acquiring sstable references
2016-08-26T14:58:50.649Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92646 |                                            Merging memtable tombstones
2016-08-26T14:58:50.650Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92656 |                                          Key cache hit for sstable 489
2016-08-26T14:58:50.651Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92657 |                            Seeking to partition beginning in data file
2016-08-26T14:58:50.651Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92845 | Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones
2016-08-26T14:58:50.652Z | /0.0.0.1 |        92847 |                             Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables
2016-08-26T14:58:50.652Z | /0.0.0.1 |        98457 |                                    Read 501 live and 0 tombstone cells
2016-08-26T14:58:50.653Z | /0.0.0.1 |        98490 |                                     Enqueuing response to /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.762Z | /0.0.0.1 |       209166 |          Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to XXXX.XXXXX.com/0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.791Z | /0.0.0.1 |       234723 |                    REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.794Z | /0.0.0.1 |       234778 |                                  Processing response from /0.0.0.1
2016-08-26T14:58:50.917Z | /0.0.0.2 |       363508 |                       Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /0.0.0.1
```

This is a fairly large cluster (15 node) cluster but the dis latency from on of the nodes is shown here:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdc               2.24   129.03  174.26    4.75 15355.69  1069.99    91.76     0.14    0.77   0.47   8.43
sdb               2.39   128.91  172.31    4.72 15189.18  1068.77    91.84     0.14    0.77   0.47   8.38
sde               2.06   126.19  172.95    4.60 15199.89  1046.10    91.50     0.14    0.77   0.47   8.41
sda               6.60   124.75    3.75   14.99   268.23  1100.15    72.99     0.02    0.86   0.52   0.98
sdd               2.27   124.49  170.66    4.54 15029.25  1032.00    91.67     0.13    0.76   0.47   8.32
dm-0              0.00     0.00    8.10    4.31    64.80    34.46     8.00     0.03    2.52   0.22   0.27
dm-1              0.00     0.00    2.26  132.38   203.39  1059.02     9.38     0.06    0.46   0.05   0.70
dm-2              0.00     0.00  175.19  130.76 15199.88  1046.10    53.10     0.11    0.34   0.28   8.42
dm-3              0.00     0.00  173.13  129.00 15029.24  1032.00    53.16     0.10    0.33   0.28   8.32
dm-4              0.00     0.00  176.70  133.75 15355.69  1069.99    52.91     0.11    0.34   0.27   8.44
dm-5              0.00     0.00  174.90  133.60 15189.17  1068.77    52.70     0.11    0.34   0.27   8.38
dm-6              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.83     0.01     6.66     8.00     0.00    0.36   0.21   0.02
```

Here is a view of I/O utilization percentages of the cluster.
[image: ioutil]

UPDATE: gc logs look a bit concerning there many (~40 per minute) 10ms+ pauses per minute

```
2016-08-29T08:40:28.194-0500: 3267605.189: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0225500 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001925 seconds
2016-08-29T08:40:28.224-0500: 3267605.218: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0282851 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002292 seconds
2016-08-29T08:40:30.313-0500: 3267607.308: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0228544 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0003854 seconds
```

Sorted the list of pauses over the last 10 hours and there are some fairly large pauses in there.

```
2016-08-29T00:10:58.821-0500: 3237035.816: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3012112 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002029 seconds
2016-08-29T06:45:12.657-0500: 3260689.652: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3115931 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002821 seconds
2016-08-29T00:14:05.523-0500: 3237222.518: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3314997 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002298 seconds
2016-08-29T08:30:36.023-0500: 3267013.017: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.3173462 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002041 seconds
```

Comment: can you include disk latency? `iostat -dx 1` ?

Comment: Often times, when random simple things seem to take ~100ms, it's either GC pauses or disk pauses. Are you using real disks or EBS/SAN/NFS? Do you have (datadog?) metrics for your young/new collections/second?

Comment: Raid0 SSDs for disk. Memory could be an issue. I don't have datadog metrics but gc logs look concerning I think (Added to question).